# Divisor Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, factorial, prime-factorization

Express the numbers $11! = 39,916,800$ and the binomial coefficient $\binom {23} {11}$, each as products of their prime factors. Do this without using your calculator in any way. Use this to calculate the greatest common divisor, and least common multiple of the two numbers. Confirm how these relate to the product of the numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express $11!$ and $\binom{23}{11}$ as products of their prime factors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991191/express-11-and-binom2311-as-products-of-their-prime-factors) (if you do not intend to do your homework on your own, then you may as well ask your classmate, who seems to have already posted this question).